# Sort Events by Start Date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I need to be able to get the events in both directions ASC/DESC using Microsoft Graph API. I'm trying the following API to achieve that:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$orderby=start
```

However, when I perform the request I get the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The $orderby expression must evaluate to a single value of primitive type.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c00d676d-ef8e-418b-8561-80e08729da71",
            "date": "2017-11-16T13:31:59"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I tried to access the date directly:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$orderby=start.dateTime
```

Got the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The child type 'start.dateTime' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "240342f5-d7f6-430b-9bd0-190dc3e1f73b",
            "date": "2017-11-16T13:32:39"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to sort events by date in ASC/DESC order?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're very close but you're referencing `DateTime` incorrectly. The proper format is `{parent}/{child}`. These will work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$orderby=start/dateTime
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$orderby=start/dateTime desc
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: here is the link to the official documentation.
It shows an example how to access complex objects with this / notation mentioned here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#orderby-parameter